# select data on click of checkbox in table

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table with checkboxes and I want to capture the data in the table rows on click of each of the checkboxes. I have a functional call `(click)="checkConditions($event, data)"` which is called on click of each checkbox.

Here data gives me all the data of the row which I want to get an array variable. The issue is that on click of the first checkbox it works fine. I get the data and I push it in an empty array but if I click the second checkbox, I lose the original data and only have the latest data. I have tried `this.checkedInstruments.push(...data);`
it gives me an error `"Found non-callable @@iterator"` in angular 8.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide your JS code

Comment: @Yogesh, could you please add the code snippet also to understand the issue better . Are you using ag-grid for implementing this?

Comment: I am not using any grid.....checkConditions(event, data: any) {
    console.log("clicked row data is", data);
    this.checkedInstruments = [];
    this.checkedInstruments.push(data);
}

Comment: Yogesh, I can see the array checkedInstruments is getting initialized again with empty array and hence you have only the latest data and not the previous one. Try declaring the checkedInstruments array at class level and check again.

Comment: Ohhh....thanks... How could I miss that????

Comment: Happy to help you ! Hope you don't mind upvoting for the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yogesh, I can see the array checkedInstruments is getting initialized again with empty array and hence you have only the latest data and not the previous one. Try declaring the checkedInstruments array at class level and check again.